# Having a blackberry J2ME and Android Project under Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry, java-me

I am building a project under netbeans with a lot of preprocessing instructions. Netbeans handle that pretty well but unfortunately it is not very well supported as an IDE for blackberry and android.

So the idea behind this question is to import the project into eclipse in order to get the new features of every plugin and ease the development. I already found a pretty nice solution for handling preprocessing instructions with Antenna, but I would like to know how to handle the multiple facets of the project : an android project with ADT, a blackberry project with its plugin and finally a J2ME project as well. My goal is to taking advantage of the best plugins eclipse has to offer.

(And the project compiles with ant, so no real problem on this side).

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Sorry but no answer actually suits me. I am looking for a way to have a sinle project with both BB, android and J2me working through precompile statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you would have to create a separate project for each Android, Blackberry etc in the *same* workspace, then you would have to define the logical dependency between those projects. So if Project A is dependent on Project B, right-click on Project A in the project tree then `Properties > Java Build Path > Projects` and add the Project B to the list of projects Project A depends on.

This will allow you to work on Project B as if it was a stand alone project and you and work on Project A as if Project B was a part of it.

You can do this with any number of projects.

Regards,

Comment: I need evrything in the *same* project, sorry.

Comment: Normally the methodology for it is to have a deployment command for your production requirements that packages all your projects into one. You can use Maven or Ant for something like this. However, you probably know best what fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

1. get BB eclipse plugin from [Blackberry site](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp)
2. install Android ADT manager from [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
3. install j2me wireless toolkit
4. create all project separately into same work space
5. use relative sdk for build path

after creating project you can also copy your source files to your project n file system, you can defile project dependency as Ali said
i reccomend to disable pre-processing,  if you are using ant to build, just disabele it from `windows` > `preference`

Comment: I need evrything in the *same* project, sorry.

Comment: you can do it in same project but condition is that you nedd to create separate ant file for each build

Comment: fuzzy. There are many problems to deal with such as preprocessing of sources that yoyu don't mention and the ability to define a set of featuers (called abilities in netbeans).

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion to you is build your project in HTML5.If you are targeting the android as well as Blackberry .I do not Know How you will do it but It will be really easy to transform the the application of Blackberry to Android.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the BlackBerry plugin from the RIM site and it is a huge download that includes Eclipse itself. Then you can add the Android plugin via the Eclipse "Install New Software" menu.

Answer (score 0):

I personally did it on my home machine and here is how How I had done

1. First install the the Eclipse plugin provided on blackberry developer site
2. Next install the android in same eclipse from Android developer site.

And voilla you are ready for `android` and `blackberry` development on single eclipse. I dont know about J2ME bcoz I no longer works on it but I think the plugin for Eclipse will do the work

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you're looking for but perhaps use Ant to do the builds, packaging etc.  That makes it easier to support multiple platforms, set preprocessor macros etc.  So the IDE would be used for mostly editing.  Note that on BB you can have the IDE refer to the .jar thus resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue. I installed Android first and was working on Google maps project .Since I shifted to Blackberry for a while, when i tried installing that plug-in,it did not accept it. Later after much research I found out that the Emulator for android was supporting Maps which inturn does not support installation of BlackBerry. Pretty weird. Like ber444 mentioned, BB plugin is a huge download file of 402 MB which consists of eclipse 3.5 support. 
 I was working on Ganneymede for android and installed indigo for BB but its not supported